# PyCharm: How do I jump to the file location in project from an open tab?

Tags: pycharm

I'm new to PyCharm and constantly find myself scrolling through the Project to find the file that I'm currently working on (that is currently open as a tab in my editor). Is there a keyboard shortcut to jump to that location?

I [STFW](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/STFW)'d but didn't find anything.

I've gone through the PyCharm Documentation's [Project tool window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/project-tool-window.html) and [Editor tabs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/settings-editor-tabs.html) but came up short.

Ideally I would have a keybinding (Like [F4](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/viewing-definition.html#table) does for definitions) that brings me to the location in the Project tool window of the file that I currently have in focus.

Comment: Like this? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/navigating-through-the-source-code.html#recent_locations

Comment: Yes! Exactly like <Alt>+<F1> followed by <Enter>. If I could do it in one combination that would be amazing, but that's a great find. TYVM!